# Parsing an uninitialized value into a function

Tags: c, memory, initialization, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a little program that goes through a list of numbers in an array and just inserts them into a binary search tree. Here's what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_t node_t;

struct node_t {
    int data;
    node_t *left;
    node_t *right;
};

int insert(node_t *node, int n);

int main(void) {
    int array[8] = {5, 8, 3, 6, 9, 2, 4, 7};
    int i;
    node_t *root;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        insert(root, array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int insert(node_t *node, int n) {

    if (node == NULL) {
        node = malloc(sizeof node);
        node->data = n;
        return 1;
    }

    if (n > node->data) {
        insert(node->left, n);

    } else if (n < node->data) {
        insert(node->right, n);

    } else {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0; // Suppress 'control reaches end of non-void function'
}
```

when I compile with gcc I get a warning saying "'root' may be used uninitialized in this function". Running it causes on errors (on Windows at least), however, printing out `root->data` in `main()` yields a 0.

The idea I was trying to implement was the `insert()` function checking if the pointer to the input node was `NULL` so it could then malloc it. Also, due to how the recursion is handled, the number being inserted should be inserted at that node. If the node did NOT equal `NULL`, then I would recursively call `insert()` again on the side of the node where the number should be inserted.

I understand the reason why this doesn't work has something to do with the pointer `root` not being directed anywhere, nor `root->left`/`root->right`, however, I don't know what I can do to fix this. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Unrelated, but what happens to the returned value from the recursive calls?

Comment: As for your problem, search for *emulating pass by reference in c*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right sorry, made a couple of edits as the code was taken from the wrong point in me trying to troubleshoot it. As far as the search goes, I might be missing something but the 3 top results on Google for that didn't seem to help, they seem to be talking about passing addresses of initialized variables into a function whereas I'm passing a pointer to an address that hasn't been told what to store.

Answer (score 1):

There might be more problem with the code you posted but I listed a few problems below.

Since it is the node that you need to allocate memory for if it contains NULL, you need to change this:

```
if (node->data == NULL) {
```

To this:

```
if (node == NULL) {
```

Also, you need to initiate the root node, since it will just contain whatever happens to be on stack at that moment and it may or may not be NULL (e.i. the thing you want to compare with in insert function). So initiate it like so:

```
node_t *root = NULL;
```

Last thing is to change to malloc to calloc function (or do a memset to zero on the memory separately). Otherwise the variables node->left and node->right can contain non NULL values that could result in making use of uninitialized memory.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, yeah I caught that first thing just before you posted I think. I've now changed the two other things you said and surely now it doesn't return any errors. However, when I go into main after the for loop and try to do `printf("%d\n", root->data);` the program crashes with no error message. Would you know what's going on there?

Comment: Remember that you need to pass the address to the memory in order to modify that piece of memory inside the function. In other words, you need to use a double pointer, otherwise the insert function will be useless.

Answer (score 1):

Your program does indeed pass an unintialized `root` variable to the `insert()`  function. But even if initialize `root` you are still going to have problems
because in order to populate the tree, you need to pass pointer to pointer (as you want to be able modify the pointer `root` in main()). Similarly, you need modify the argument to
the recursive calls to `insert()` as well.

I notice you don't really use the return value of `insert()`. So, it can just be a `void` function. I added some in-code comments to explain some problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_t node_t;

struct node_t {
    int data;
    node_t *left;
    node_t *right;
};

void print(node_t *r) { /* In order tree traversal. Gives the sorted output. */
    if (!r) return;
    print(r->left);
    printf("%d ", r->data);
    print(r->right);
}

void insert(node_t **node, int n);

int main(void) {
    int array[] = {5, 8, 3, 6, 9, 2, 4, 7};     /* Removed the size. It can be calculated using sizeof and helps when array size changes */
    int i;
    node_t *root = NULL;

    /* Without hard-coding, array size can be calculated like this. */
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof array/sizeof array[0]; i++) {
        insert(&root, array[i]);
    }

    print(root);
    return 0;
}

void insert(node_t **node, int n) {
    if (*node == NULL) {
        *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    if (*node == NULL) { /* Need to check the return value for failure. */
            perror("malloc");
            exit(1);
        }
    (*node)->left = (*node)->right = NULL;
        (*node)->data = n;
    return;
    }

    if (n < (*node)->data) /* Insert smaller elements on the left for it to be a binary tree - but not neccessary */
        insert(&(*node)->left, n);
     else  /* Another else below this isn't needed. There can't be any error with the number 'n' itself */
        insert(&(*node)->right, n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I tried to run your program and it compiles fine but when I run it it crashes without an error message (I'm on Windows). As far as the pointer to pointer stuff, thanks for clearing that up! When I googled around earlier that was a way I came across but it seemed too messy to be right, but it seems it is after all. In any case, is there anything I can do about the crashing?

Comment: @Arkantos Did you modify your existing program? I don't see any problem with the code I posted. Perhaps, you tried to modify your program with my suggestions and missed some (such as `node_t *root = NULL;`)? In any case, you can run through the debugger to find which line of code causes the crash.